# Flex Spark Border Only On 3 Sides of Button

Tags: apache-flex, button, border, customization, flex-spark

I have a skin class whose host component is a Toggle Button. I need to be able to add a border around it but only on the top, left, and right sides, As I understand it you have to the: `<s:Line>` component. So I added:

```
<s:Line   left="0" top="0" right="0">
    <s:stroke>

        <s:LinearGradientStroke  rotation="180" weight="2" caps="square">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                             alpha="0"
                             alpha.selectedStates="1"/>

            <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                             alpha="0" 
                             alpha.selectedStates="1" />
        </s:LinearGradientStroke>

    </s:stroke>
</s:Line>
```

This worked for the top line , But I can't seem to get the left and right lines. I tried: this for the left side line, but it did not work (no line showed up):

```
<s:Line   left="0" top="0">
    <s:stroke>

        <s:LinearGradientStroke  rotation="90" weight="2" caps="square">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                             alpha="0"
                             alpha.selectedStates="1"/>

            <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                             alpha="0" 
                             alpha.selectedStates="1" />
        </s:LinearGradientStroke>

    </s:stroke>
</s:Line>
```

How can I achieve the 3 Lines around the button?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- TOP -->
    <s:Line   left="0" top="0"  right="0"> 
        <s:stroke>

            <s:LinearGradientStroke  rotation="180" weight="1" caps="round" >
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                                 alpha="0"
                                 alpha.selectedStates="1"/>

                <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                                 alpha="0" 
                                 alpha.selectedStates="1" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>

        </s:stroke>
    </s:Line>


    <!-- LEFT -->
    <s:Line   left="0" top="0"  bottom="0"> 
        <s:stroke>

            <s:LinearGradientStroke  rotation="180" weight="1" caps="round" >
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                                 alpha="0"
                                 alpha.selectedStates="1"/>

                <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                                 alpha="0" 
                                 alpha.selectedStates="1" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>

        </s:stroke>
    </s:Line>


    <!-- RIGHT -->
    <s:Line   right="0" top="0"  bottom="0"> 
        <s:stroke>

            <s:LinearGradientStroke  rotation="180" weight="1" caps="round" >
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                                 alpha="0"
                                 alpha.selectedStates="1"/>

                <s:GradientEntry color="0xffffff" 
                                 alpha="0" 
                                 alpha.selectedStates="1" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>

        </s:stroke>
    </s:Line>
```